# Devise with ldap without database in activeadmin

Tags: devise, ldap, activeadmin

I want to use active admin for my app but i want to auth users by ldap server without needing to create database for users. 
Is this even possible?

Now my app use basic http auth which i dont like a lot
I'm looking for solution that will help me to auth user for actve admin only by piece of code like this:

```
ldap = Net::LDAP.new  :host => 'ip'
ldap.auth "uid=#{name.split('@').first},ou=Users,dc=huzar,dc=pl",password
ldap.bind
```